# Updating a div with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to update an `h3` with the id `data` using Ajax. The Ajax uses a get request to retrive data from an API, but for some reason the html is not being updated.

This is what the json data looks like `{ticker: "TEST", Price: 7876}`

I tried to change `$('#data').text(data[0].data[]);` to `$('#data').text(data[ticker].data[]);`, for example, but it didn't work either.

I added a `console.log(data[0])` to debug it, and the data normally appears in my console.

```
function doPoll(){

    $.get('http://localhost:8000/tst/', function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
        $('#data').text(data[0].data);
        setTimeout(doPoll, 1000);
    });
} 

doPoll();
```

And this is the html part to be updated:

```
<h3 id="data"></h3>
```

Basically instead of that h3 there should be my data updated every tot seconds, but at the actual moment nothing appears.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `data[]` ? You will receive Unexpected syntax. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error when creating the question

Comment: what do you get in ` console.log(data[0]);`  and which part do you want so show in `h3` tag?

Comment: @user404 i get the json data correctly

Comment: with the console i got {ticker: "TEST", Price: 7876}

Comment: @Jack022, please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should convert your `raw` response to `json`.

`data = JSON.parse(data);`

Then, If the response data looks like,

`{ticker: "TEST", Price: 7876}`

Then, you can't get data like `data[0].data`. You can get ticker name with `data.ticker` and you can get price with `data.price`.

If your response data looks like,

```
[
 {
   ticker: "TEST",
   price: 7876
 }
]
```

Then your will get data like,

`data[0].ticker` and `data[0].price`

Comment: i added data = JSON.parse(data);, but i got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

Comment: Check the type of `data` using `console.log(typeof data)`. If your data is already in JSON format, Then ignore that step. Can you share the screen shot of the response from the API ?

Comment: You mean what i got in the console?

Comment: yeah.. Exactly.

Comment: Ok, i got this, basically i only had to change .data to .ticker or .price, the data was already in json, so it did not have to be parsed

Comment: Ok. In console, what are getting for `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: this {ticker: "TEST", Price: 7876}

Comment: Then you can get data individually using `$('#data').text(data.ticker)` **or** `$('#data').text(data.Price)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have got  your data correctly from  `data[0]`;
So if you want to show `ticker` or `Price`, you can do this way:

```
$('#data').text(data[0]["ticker"]);
```

or for **Price**:

```
$('#data').text(data[0]["Price"]);
```

## update

**N.B.: Please make sure you are using proper attribute-name containing in your data i.e ticker, Price**

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is what i have been suggested do to in the other answer. Basically the json data was already parsed, so i did not have to add anything, seems to work now

Answer (score 1):

To access the ajax response you need to parse that response data.

For e.g: `data=JSON.parse(data);`

Now you can you use this data to change the text of `<h3>`

Answer (score 0):

data looks like an array of objects, so you'd call

```
data[0].ticker
data[0].Price
```

the answer you marked correct, has a lower case "p" in price which will not return the right value as JS is case sensitive.